# Получить данные по WebSocket (API) через php

Tags: php, api, http, websocket

https://docs.eltex-co.ru/ecss/ispol-zovanie-tehnologii-websocket-120295637.html
Есть данная документация. Возможно из-за отсутствия практики, мне не понятно, как ее запустить.

Цель: получить данные в JSON
Вопрос: Как отправить запрос через php в данное API, чтобы на выходе получить данные?

Вроде есть HTTP API - но тоже не могу разобраться.
В интернете по данному API информации 0.

P.S.
Перепробовал все возможные способы (Ответы от англоязычного stackoverflow).
Api включен. Хост известен.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/331462/

Comment: Речь совсем о другом.